# postman ssl issue when post https request

Tags: https, postman

Installed postman from Chrome.

Getting error related to ssl certificate when posting https request.

Looks postman could not have SSL handshake with server, although server is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

**2021 Update:**

For those interested to configure properly your certificates within Postman, please follow the below tutorials:

- [Postman: Working with certificates](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)
- [How to Troubleshoot SSL Certificate & Server Connection Issues](https://blog.postman.com/self-signed-ssl-certificate-troubleshooting/)

---

***Old solution, only disabling the SSL verification.***

For anyone having this trouble.

> Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
> Fix this by **turning off 'SSL certificate verification'** in ***Settings > General***

So, just try to `disable` the `SSL certificates` in the `Postman Settings`.

After that, Postman was able to normally make POST requests through HTTPS.

*Source: Postman help.*

Comment: Did that,did not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Totally worked for me, thank you Juliano Macedo

Comment: Can't we use certificate verification for self-signed certificates?

Comment: Hi @Kanad yes, now is possible. I updated my answer with the necessary steps to follow to do that. I hope it can help you. Have a good week.

Answer (score -3):

Open chrome and directly posting the https url for the post request, then reopen postman it works. Chrome browser did the SSL handshake and past the info to postman so postman can continue with https request.