# Add certificates to Postman to connect to Go server

Tags: go, https, postman

I followed the following [tutorial](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/Security/SSL/GeneratingCertificationsAndKeys.htm). So, I added server.crt and server.key to server initialization

```
err = r.RunTLS(":8080", "/users/myuser/server.crt", "/users/myuser/server.key")
```

Then I tried to send a request to Postman. For this purpose, I added certificate to Postman:

```
Host
localhost:8080
CRT file
/Users/myuser/client.crt
KEY file
/Users/myuser/client.key
Passphrase
•••••
```

But when I send the request I got this error - SSL Error: Unable to verify the first certificate. I know that I can disable SSL verification but it seems that there should be an option to do it without disabling it. Can you please help me

Comment: To validate a self-signed server cert, you need the public key for the CA on the client side. Why do you have a client cert? Are you trying to do client auth using certs?

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks for the answer! so do you mean that I should add `servercakey.pem` to CA certificates and remove all client certificates?

Comment: The public key is serverca

Comment: You can try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55975893/6689024

Answer (score 1):

https://untrusted-root.badssl.com/

THis an example website ,

Client certificates are used for authentication of client, while CA certificates is to authenticate the identity of the server.

Incase of ssl certificate , you just need to add the correct Root CA to postman.

1. TO do this open the website in browser:
2. Click on the certificate error and click view certificate

[image]

3. CLick on cert path and click root cert and click view

[image]

4. Now click details and select copy to file

[image]

5. [image]
6. browse and give a new file name

[image]

7. Add the created file to postman

[image]

**Note:** you can also disable SSL validation all together from settings